# What is the best semantic way to approach this design: a list of articles where the image header uses an image from the latest entry?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

This is a design of an article list under the category "News":

[image: An image with the text overlay 'News', followed by 4 article teasers and a 'see more' link]

The top image is actually the featured image of the latest article (in this case, it's "Hilary Presents Herself..."'s featured image). If someone publishes a new article, the top image will change.

So, technically, to keep it semantic, I make the HTML element looks something like this:

```html
<section>
   <h1>News</h1>
   <ul>
      <li>
        <figure>
        <img src="image.jpg" class="entry-image"/> <!-- notice the image -->
        </figure>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

Problem is, with this HTML structure, I have to position the article's featured image outside of its flow (using `position: absolute`) and that could make the design wonky.

It would be safer to use this structure:

```
<section>
   <figure>
   <img src="image.jpg" class="entry-image"/> <!-- image is now here -->
   </figure>
   <h1>News</h1>
   <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <h2>Entry title</h2>
        <span>Category / 01 Jan 2016</span>
      </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

So I don't have to use `position: absolute` to have it on top of the list. However, I'm not sure if it's semantic. Because the top image is actually the latest article's image, not the category's image (not the News' image).

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Will visitors even realize that the image belongs to the first news post? When I looked at your image (without reading the context), I had assumed it’s just some random background image (decoration) for the news section. Or in other words: Should this image convey relevant information, or do you only place it there because it looks nice?

Comment: @unor: the image should convey relevant information: it's the headline of the day. The mockup didn't seem to show this well (with the lorem ipsum pics and text), but with context it should look something like this: http://i.imgur.com/IisNl8y.png

Comment: 2016 seems pretty quaint now from these headlines.